# Can docbook generate output in Apples Help Book format

Tags: macos, docbook, apple-help

Can docbook output in Apples Help Book format, I know I can generate html, pdf ectera but what about Apples Help Book format (which is the standard format for help on OSX).

**EDIT**:Appears it does not but in case useful to anyone this is how I worked round it.

- Copy HelpBook from another application to give me structure, renamed
  parts as neccessary to my application.
- Wrote my docbook.xml
- Set options to supress headers and footers
- Generated xhtml chunks from docbook
- Copied xhtml pages to help book pgs folder
- Make any manual edits as necessary
- Manually created Apple Help Book index page, creating hyperlinks to my chunked xtml pages
- Run Apple Help Indexer to generate Help Index
- Modify my applications plist to reference the helpbook

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it can.

The only app I know of that specifically targets the Apple Help Book format is this one: http://www.putercraft.com